# No internet via GPON when using different equipment

Tags: networking, router, fiber

My ISP provided the following router: ZTE ZXHN F680. It is not very powerful, so I wanted to use my TP-Link Archer AX23, but because this router does not have a built-in GPON interface, I've purchased a TP-Link MC220L media converter and an SC GPON Module.

I can connect all the equipment, but there is no physical link on the media converter. The same optical cable works when connected to the ZTE.

I don't have much knowledge in optical networking, so before assuming that some equipment that I've bought is simply faulty, I wanted to check if maybe I order the wrong equipment from the beginning.

Comment: What sort of optical port does the ISP provided router have.  be as specific as possible y editing your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: Is the connector you purchased Class B+ of Class C+?Does the ISP router support Class B+ or Class C+?

Comment: After looking at the specifications for TP-Link MC220L (if you could call what I looked at specifications), we will need to know more about the GPON module you purchased.  This might be as simple as a provisioning issue which is something only your ISP can resolve